# How to use AuthenticationManager SignIn when using OpenId

Tags: authentication, cookies, model-view-controller, openid, owin

We have a need to provide Mixed Mode Authentication and we've spent weeks chasing down samples, and bits and pieces and finally we have our ClaimsIdentity properly built, we just need to figure out a way to have OWIN recognize our ClaimsIdentity as the logged in user.

Everything we've found thus far is defining app.UseCookieAutentication in Startup.Auth.ConfigureAuth().  Set AuthenticationType = "Cookies", then set a login path.

However, we use a custom version of Identity Server 3 and in addition to UseCookieAuthentication, we also use app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication.

We've had issues with setting the UseCookieAuthentication LoginPath.  We've tried putting something in it and leaving it empty.

Code we use to login our Windows users, we make calls to IdentityServer, get our tokens and claims.

We then use UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync as follows.

var _identity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(_slUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

Everything appears good here.

Then we use that Identity with the following code:

var _ctx = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();

var _authenticationManager = _ctx.Authentication;
_authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, _identity);

The code runs but when we check _ctx.Authentication.User, the identity we created still isn't showing up which results in a user getting redirected to the login page on the Identity Server.

So in summary, we're trying to figure out how to take a ClaimsIdentity we've authenticated and built up in code and have it become of apart of the OwinContexts Authentication.User.Identities so it will be available throughout our application.

Comment: After this post, I found a post on how to create your own AuthenticationHandler.  In the aspx file for which we are manually authenticating and building a ClaimsPrincipal for a windows user, just to test, we are assigning the ClaimsPrincipal to Session.

Comment: Then in the AuthenticateCoreAsync(), we are using that ClaimsPrincipal to built return an AuthenticationTicket.  At that point and time, the OwinContext User is populated, but when the user gets to the home page which requires authorization, the OwinContext User Identity is back to a Generic principal